# Is there a way to mount next page before UnMount the previous one?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to create transitions between pages, but I want that at some point we see the previous page at the same time that the next one. I can't find anywhere in the nuxt3 documentation something that could serve this purpose. Is it even possible ? for now I am using onBeforeRouteLeave, but this is not the behavior intended :(

Or at least, is there a way to hijack the nuxt router and write my own